# Vertex BigQueryCreateModelJobOp `query_parameters` Format

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

The [Python SDK](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.0.0/api/v1/bigquery.html#v1.bigquery.BigqueryCreateModelJobOp) for BigQuery components shows an option for passing `query_parameters` to the `BigqueryCreateModelJobOp` PipelineTask. This task shows that it expects a `list`. I can't find any example of how to specify parameters as a list here. For a specific example:

```
BigqueryCreateModelJobOp(
                    project="silly-demo-project",
                    location="country-region1",
                    query="SELECT * FROM {{ params.table }}",
                    query_parameters=["table=silly-demo-project.dataset.cooltable"]
                )
```

The above doesn't work - so what should `query_parameters` look like here?

Comment: What error are you catching?  Also I looked in to a bit to Google's documentation this line of code might be a good reference: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/35627d145a41d57768f19d4392ef235928e00f72/samples/client_query_w_named_params.py#L32C1-L32C1

Comment: I'm getting a JSON decode error. Looking at the `google-cloud-pipeline-components` that defines the Task, it's expecting a string that embeds into another JSON string. That link is what I think may be expected, but considering the task is defined in a Kubeflow Pipeline, and so the query parameters may some from output of preceeding tasks, it doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no standard `BigQueryCreateModelJobOp` class or method format in the standard Python libraries or Google Cloud Vertex libraries. The `query\_parameters` parameter should be a list of **dictionaries**, with each dictionary containing details about the query parameter, such as its `name`, `type`, and `value`.

```
query_parameters = [
    {
        "name": "table",
        "parameterType": {"type": "STRING"},
        "parameterValue": {"value": "silly-demo-project.dataset.cooltable"}
    }
]

bigquery_task = BigqueryCreateModelJobOp(
    project="silly-demo-project",
    location="country-region1",
    query="SELECT * FROM {{ params.table }}",
    query_parameters=query_parameters
)
```

Remember, the specific structure of the query_parameters dictionary may vary based on the requirements of the library you're using.